# Transparent background UIView drawRect circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am drawing a circle with a white stroke and a color specified by a property using this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextClearRect(contextRef, rect);

    // Set the border width
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 1.5);

    // Set the circle fill color to GREEN
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    BOOL didConvert = [_routeColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, red, green, blue, 1.0);

    // Set the cicle border color to BLUE
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0);

    // Fill the circle with the fill color
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);

    // Draw the circle border
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);
}
```

The image I get back looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove the black?

Comment: Suggestion - get rid of the calls to `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` and `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`. Instead, do the following: `[_routeColor setFill]; [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];`. And FYI - color values need to be in the range 0.0 - 1.0 so all of your 255.0 values should be 1.0.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set the `backgroundColor` of the view to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Note that setting the background color only needs to be done once, when the view is created.

Comment: To add to this answer - set the background color in the custom view's `init` method, not in `drawRect:`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I've added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 19):

I needed this. When I set this, worked.

```
self.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Swift 3:

```
self.isOpaque = false
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: As @ndnguyen said you need to set these properties inside the init methods

Comment: You can also set them in a storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set background color to clearColor in init.

Here is the example

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if(self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextClearRect(contextRef, rect);

    // Set the border width
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 1.5);

    // Set the circle fill color to GREEN
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    BOOL didConvert = [_routeColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, red, green, blue, 1.0);

    // Set the cicle border color to BLUE
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0);

    // Fill the circle with the fill color
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);

    // Draw the circle border
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);
}
```